# Drupal Commerce Products for printing company

Tags: drupal, product-variations, commerce

I'm new to Commerce I hope some kind fellow could give me some directions here.

I am creating an ecommerce website for a printing company. I will give an example of what I require

For instance they will offer A6 flyers but these come in different specifications each with differing prices

Here is an example:

http://4frontdesigns.co.uk/Untitled-1.jpg

So down the left column are quantities of flyers and along thw top different speciifications of those flyers with the prices shown in the middle.

Any help much appreciated

Can I just add each variation of these one by one as it is not possible to just say that a certain additional attribute to the product will add so much $$ to the base price.

Would I just add each variation one by one then some how pull these all into one display?

Comment: I would try to create one product with 4 variations (4/0 in, 4/0 out..., use an attribute field), and manage the quantity / price relation with this module : https://drupal.org/project/commerce_price_table which provides a new field type. Add a price table field to your product (7 values for your 7 quantity ranges). Never tried this module but it could do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the commerce price table module like Flo suggested or look at the Price attributes Module https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_pricing_attributes
It uses option sets and then add to (or subtract from) the price based on the selected attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to create each product variation as its own product. So every variation gets added  as a separate product.

If you are wondering how to add different variations to  product such as paper size or colour, you would do this with taxonomy. Simply create a taxonomy term called colour and then add all the colours into this term that you would require.

Then when you create your product type in commerce, you would add this as an option to choose from when adding products by doing the following. Go to manange fields for the product type you want to add it for and add a new field, type of data = term reference. You will then select the desired taxonomy term and also there will be an option to 'Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms.' - You want to select this!

Then what you do is create a product display and pull all these in to a single page, which then gives you drop down options to change, and the price changes accordingly in real time.

You can create a product display by creating a new content type first, call it product display... Then add a field to this content type which is a 'product reference'.

Now add new content, pick to create a product display (what we have just created) and choose the products that you want to appear on that page.

Then automatically Drupal Commerce will take care of the rest. Hope this helps someone!